# Retrieve submit label using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the html as follows

```
<div class="element-container" id="div_3">
    <div id="submit_submit" class="element">
        <div class="fleft">
            <input type="submit" value="Click me!" name="submit" id="submit"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clr"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i click on **element-container** i want the label of submit button i.e. ***Click me!***

Please give a solution , I've tried `$('#submit').attr('value')`. but i didn't get the result

Comment: You should not use submit as the name for a form element, please see http://markushedlund.com/dev-tech/unable-to-javascript-submit-a-form-using-jquery for more about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a built-in method in jQuery for returning the value of `INPUT` elements, `val()`. The following should work:

```
$('#submit').val();
```

I've never tried it with a submit button specifically though.

Comment: i think it didn't get because of id, name have the value submit . Is it a reserved word ?